# nested navigator pushedNamedAndRemoveUntil predicate route is null

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I'm trying to pushedNamedAndRemoveUntil but I'm noticing that my predicate keeps returning null as the route.

My code:

```
Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
  context, 'search/studyPage',
  (Route<dynamic> route) {
    print(route);
    return false; // im returning false to illustrate that all the routes being "popped" are all returning null
    }, 
  arguments: StudyPageArgs(widget.study)
);
```

This prints:

```
MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(RouteSettings("null", null), 
animation: AnimationController#117d7(⏭ 1.000; paused; 
for MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(null)))
MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(RouteSettings("null", null), 
animation: AnimationController#117d7(⏭ 1.000; paused; 
for MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(null)))
MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(RouteSettings("null", null), 
animation: AnimationController#117d7(⏭ 1.000; paused; 
for MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(null)))
MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(RouteSettings("null", null), 
animation: AnimationController#117d7(⏭ 1.000; paused; 
for MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(null)))
```

When i do this, I am able to push to my previous route but popping from there just gives me a blank screen. It's because the predicate keeps returning null, so all previous routes are removed from the tree. Any idea what is happening?

Please keep in mind that I am using a nested navigator set-up, identical to my other question here: ([.popUntil with nested navigators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58574801/popuntil-with-nested-navigators))

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`settings` parameter is necessary:

```dart
MaterialPageRoute(builder: builder, settings:  settings
```

Comment: Indeed! It is not enough to provide a name of the router using NavigatorState.pushNamed, the RouteSettings must be also redirected into the route object manually (MaterialPageRoute in this case).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a hacky and poor way of doing this. it still works tho

```
Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
  context, 'search/studyPage',
  (Route<dynamic> route) {
setState(() {
  _popper = _popper + 1;
});
if (_popper == 4) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
}, arguments: StudyPageArgs(widget.study));
```